# How to install 11.04 on a different partition?

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 7 installed. The Hard disk is composed of C: for windows 7, D: recovery; E: HP tools. I want to install Ubuntu on a different partition to be safe in case I need to remove either windows or Ubuntu without any problems.

Another question: Does the dual boot using automatic partition by Ubuntu to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you boot to the graphical installer (not the installer in Windows) then you'll be able to choose which harddisk to install it on. If you already have Windows installed there, then you can choose how much disk space each operating system shall have. It's just a slider from 0% to 100%, although those extremes won't be valid if you want to have both. :)

The installer will add entries to your boot menu automatically so that you can choose between Windows and Ubuntu when you start the computer.

Answer (score -2):

Avoid using automatic-anything on a computer that already has an OS installed on it.

What you should do, for example by using *GParted* from a Ubuntu Live CD, is to re-size one of your partitions (preferably your largest) so that you shrink it. It will then leave x amount of *unallocated* space, which you can select and then use to create a brand new partition where you will later install Ubuntu on.

Repeat the process, but this time, create yet another partition that is slightly larger than your RAM.

When installing Ubuntu put it on the large empty partition you created above, using a ext filesystem. You will want to mount it as "/". Mount the other smaller partition as "swap", and then start the install.

To answer your other question: Dual booting doesn't touch your partitions. To speak of dual booting is just to say that you have a computer with two OS:s on it, and that you, when you start it up, are allowed to choose which one you will boot up.

Comment: Why on earth should you want to "avoid using automatic-anything"? The most important thing a computer can be used for, is to automate boring things. It is a lot more likely that a human does something wrong. Automation helps prevent errors.

Comment: I think you're entitled to your own methodology when installing an OS and wouldn't suggest it must always end badly. However, my own experience from Ubuntu installations and using the "automagic" settings are more on the dark side - the few times I choose that lane it simply never ended up as expected _for me_. That of course says little about this specific case, albeit what I suggest will give him more control and hopefully a better understanding of what's actually happening.